# Issue with UserControl event not being intercepted with MVVM Light EventToCommand

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light, eventtocommand

I have a WPF project where I am using MVVM Light. On a page in the project, `ConnectionPage`, I have a UserControl (`ctlSqlConnection`) that can raise a `Connected` event. I am trying to use MVVM Light to intercept this event with `EventToCommand` and execute a command called `NavigateToDatabasePageCommand` on the `ConnectionPage`'s viewmodel (not the UserControl's own ViewModel!), but this doesn't appear to be working. That is, nothing is happening.

The `DataContext` of `ConnectionPage` is being set ok as the UI of the page is being populated correctly.

I know the event is being raised as I've also wired up a traditional .NET handler and this is being hit.

I am using version 5.3 of MVVM Light in case this has any bearing?

I'm new to MVVM and the toolkit, so I expect I'm doing something silly.

### Update

I've since looked at the event itself in the UserControl which is declared as

```
public event EventHandler<ConnectionSettingViewModel> Connected;
```

But when I put another non generic event handler instead like:

```
        public event EventHandler ConnectedWithNoArgs;
```

this makes it work!?

So,

1. Does that mean the Interaction part can't deal with generic event declarations, or am I not doing something right?
2. How would I get to pass EventArgs from the event to the Nav() method

Here is the XAML for `ConnectionPage`:

```
<Page
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" 
x:Class="Views.ConnectionPage"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:data="clr-namespace:Utilities.Data;assembly=Utilities"
xmlns:util="clr-namespace:Utilities.Data;assembly=Utilities"
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
xmlns:command="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform"

mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
Title="ConnectionPage"
DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=ConnectionPageViewModel}" x:Name="connPage" >

<Grid x:Name="rootGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Label Grid.Row="0" Content="Create / Select Sql Server connection" Style="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}"/>

    <util:SqlServerConnectionControl Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ctlSqlConnection" DataContext="{Binding SqlServerConnectionControlViewModel}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Connected">
                <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ElementName=connPage, Path=DataContext.NavigateToDatabasePageCommand}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </util:SqlServerConnectionControl>
</Grid>
```

Here is the `ConnectionPageViewModel` :

```
    public class ConnectionPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    SqlServerConnectionControlViewModel _serverCtrlVM;
    Avalon _avalon;
    IFrameNavigationService _navService;

    public ConnectionPageViewModel(IFrameNavigationService navigationService, Avalon avalon)
    {
        _avalon = avalon;
        _navService = navigationService;
        _serverCtrlVM = new SqlServerConnectionControlViewModel(avalon.ConnectionStringManager);

        NavigateToDatabasePageCommand = new RelayCommand(Nav);
    }
    private void Nav()
    {
       // NOT GETTING HERE!!!
        _navService.NavigateTo("DatabasePage");
    }

    public SqlServerConnectionControlViewModel SqlServerConnectionControlViewModel
    {
        get { return _serverCtrlVM; }
    }

    public RelayCommand NavigateToDatabasePageCommand { get; private set; }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think I've figured it out in case this helps anyone else.

The `Connected` Event is
`public event EventHandler<ConnectionSettingViewModelEventArgs> Connected;`

I added `PassEventArgsToCommand="True"` to the `EventToCommand` xaml.
I changed `RelayCommand` to `RelayCommand<T>` where T: EventArgs (this is the important bit!) and used `ConnectionSettingViewModelEventArgs` as T.